# Allow user to choose from different Tile Sources in osmdroid

Tags: osmdroid

I want to add a map chooser to my osmdroid app, so the user can choose different map types at runtime (e.g. mapnik, Bing maps, opencyclemap etc). Similar to the way you can do that in other map applications e.g. Google maps, leaflet etc.

Does osmdroid provide a UI out-of-the-box to do this? Or do I have to build the UI myself?

I have searched online and couldn't find any mention of anyone wanting to do this. It seems like it would be a very common use case.

For example, leaflet (the browser version) allows you to pass in an array of tilesources, and it automatically adds a dropdown to the map that lets you choose which map to display.

As far as I can tell, MapView only has a setTileSource(ITileSource) method.

Just to be clear, I don't want to display two map styles at once. I want the user to be able to choose from a list of tile sources.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct about setting tile sources, but you do have to build your own UI for it, if you want to allow the user to change it at runtime

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The Bot is stupid.  Saying a feature dose not exist is hard to prove with any type of citation or documentation.  The feature is not there.  The lack of any documentation is the relevant thing.  Saying you can improve the answer with it is not really true.